# Can someone point me what's the type of encoding used in

Tags: geolocation, encoding

I am trying to understand the type of encoding used to represent a poly line on earth from [here.com Platform Data Extension service](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/map_data_nds_layers/data-layer-tile) requesting ROAD_GEOM_FC layer.

```
"LAT":"5013674,12,12,16","LON":"865514,-13,-12,-17","ZLEVEL":",,1,"
```

Can someone point me to RFC or some documentation about it.

Comment: It appears that here.com provides several different services.  Which service provided you with that output?

Comment: Platform Data Extension. Especially the current result is from a query requesting ROAD_GEOM_FC layer.